# Load testing OAuth2 Authorization Code Grant (with JMeter)

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, load-testing

We have implemented an OAuth2 Authorization Server (and Identity Provider).
Now we want to perform load tests to gage system performance.

The concrete problem I have now, is that I want to load test an Authorization Code  Flow. 
I have been using JMeter so far. But I have no clue how to provide an endpoint for the required redirect_uri, to complete the flow.
Is there any way to do this at all, or am I out of luck? Google was no help.
If JMeter can't do it, is there a tool that can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide whatever `redirect_uri` parameter you want, i.e. `http://localhost:8081/oauth/login` and fetch the required parameters from the response [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)

Of course the sampler will fail as most probably you don't have anything running on your machine which could serve as a redirect target so either use [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server) to provide a stub or just mark the sampler as successful by adding Response Assertion to it and ticking `Main sample and sub-samples` and `Ignore Status` boxes

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I kinda tripped up myself.
I was in the head space of implementing a client, but I'm playing the user agent here. Silly me.
Extracting the redirect URL + Response Assertion worked like a charm.